# Formulas to determine how the processor stores integers in certain bits

Tags: c, memory-management, integer

I have thought for a bit, and for 4 byte integers I came up with the following formula:

`32(^4) * 256 * 8`

Which actually really returns the 4 byte integer range. I am not really sure how.
**Is it correct, why and if not.. how do i think of it?**

With that formula I can calculate easily any range.

Comment: 32^4 = (2^5)^4 = 2^20, 256 = 2^8, 8 = 2^3, 20+8+3 = 31, eg. your "formule" is nothing more than 2^31. So whats the problem? Your question is unclear. Are you asking how architectures store [endian-representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)?

Comment: @WhozCraig 8 is 2^3, not 2^4...

Comment: @DrewMcGowen thanks Drew. I total spaced she was working with signed values. thanks for the correction

Comment: There is a difference between LSB and MSB architecture. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Make a formule that i understand that caculates ranges. It explains how the range can be stored in 32 bits for example.
Also i might use that in a function that automatically declare variables according to the value given. Isn't that nice.

Comment: How a computer stores an integer is an abstraction. You'll need to cast to (void *) to access the underlying memory. They you can apply masks with bitwise `and` and/or `or`.

Comment: Yeah i can deal with that. The real thing is if i succeed in desribing the formule from above. Also i don't really understand it.

Comment: Could you multiply by 2 and test until the result decreases to determine the bits you have to work with? And use a similar process to test the negative range?

Comment: There's no way you can know how the processor stores a value, if you want the value range of a type, that's a different problem. Your formula has no meaning

Answer (score 2):

You could use the constants defined in [limits.h](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/) to test whether your values will fit in the variables you have provided.

Comment: Good idea.. However thats not an option for me. I can't include any libraries but the already included standart ones. Elseway i would use `limits.h`

Comment: [limits.h and stdint.h](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits) are defined by the standard

Answer (score 1):

In [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) (which is the representation used by almost all modern computers), the range of a signed integer of `k` bits is `-2k-1 — 2k-1-1`, inclusive. In [sign-magnitude and one's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations#Signed_magnitude_representation) representations, there are two possible representations for 0 and the range is symmetric: `-(2k-1-1) — 2k-1-1`.

If you need to represent this in portable C, you need to worry about integer overflow. Also, without `limits.h` you have no good way to know what the bit-length of an `int` is. Non-portably, if you believe that `int` has 32 bits (which is *not* guaranteed), then you could use `((1UL<<31)-1)` as the largest possible signed integer.

Comment: Can't i check the `int`'s bit lenght with `sizeof(int)*8` ?

Comment: @Edenia: No. It is not guaranteed that a byte has 8 bits; it could have more. And it is not guaranteed that an `int` uses all the bits in its representation; it might use fewer.

Comment: Why would it use fewer? The compiler i use have no optimizations expect some code removal. Also it works with C89.
So there is no way to do that without any libraries?
And the formule i have provided is invalid / could be / in my environment?

Comment: @Edenia: it might use fewer for various reasons. One example is that a bit could be reserved as a parity bit. Or because the chip only supports 24-bit arithmetic. Or whatever. It's not common, but it is allowed by the standard. Your formula is the same as mine, but rather more complicated: 256 is 2^8, 32 is 2^5 and 8 is 2^3. So 32^4 * 256 * 8 is (2^5)^4 * 2^8 * 2^3 == 2^20 * 2^8 * 2*3 == 2^(20+8+3) == 2^31.

Comment: You mean, mine formula is more complicated? I just used my nearest logic.. based on my bmp managment knowledge. For e.g how you can store 16m colors in 3 bytes. Thats probably from where my logic is influenced by.